# AVL Tree deletion results in incorrect traversal

Tags: c, data-structures

Made a C Program menu to insert, delete and print data from AVL Tree. But something is wrong after deletion.

The results of the AVL Tree transversal print that has been input are correct, but when deleting it and print it again it looks like something is wrong.

Here what i input: : 6, 27, 19, 11, 36, 14, 81, 63, 75
And here the output transversal:
Preorder traversal: 19 11 6 14 36 27 75 63 81
Inorder traversal: 6 11 14 19 27 36 63 75 81
Postorder traversal: 6 14 11 27 63 81 75 36 19

And i believe it is correct.

But after deletion for:  14, 75, 36, 19, 11
Preorder traversal: 27 6 63 81
Inorder traversal: 6 27 63 81
Postorder traversal: 6 81 63 27

I think its incorrect because it should be:
Preorder traversal: 63 6 27 81
Inorder traversal: 27 6 63 81
Postorder traversal: 27 6 81 63

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    int height;
};

int height(struct Node* node){
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    return node->height;
}

int max(int a, int b){
    return (a>b)? a : b;
}

struct Node* newNode(int data){
    struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->height = 1;
    return node;
}

struct Node* rightRotate(struct Node* y){
    struct Node* x = y->left;
    struct Node* T2 = x->right;

    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;

    return x;
}

struct Node* leftRotate(struct Node* x){
    struct Node* y = x->right;
    struct Node* T2 = y->left;

    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;

    return y;
}

int getBalance(struct Node* node){
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(node->left) - height(node->right);
}

struct Node* insert(struct Node* node, int data){
    if(node == NULL)
        return newNode(data);

    if(data < node->data)
        node->left = insert(node->left, data);
    else if(data > node->data)
        node->right = insert(node->right, data);
    else 
        return node;

    node->height = 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));

    int balance = getBalance(node);

    if(balance > 1 && data < node->left->data)
        return rightRotate(node);

    if(balance < -1 && data > node->right->data)
        return leftRotate(node);

    if(balance > 1 && data > node->left->data) {
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }

    if(balance < -1 && data < node->right->data) {
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    return node;
}

struct Node* minValueNode(struct Node* node){
    struct Node* current = node;

    while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}

struct Node* deleteNode(struct Node* root, int data){
    if(root == NULL)
        return root;

    if(data < root->data)
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, data);

    else if(data > root->data)
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, data);

    else{
        if((root->left == NULL) || (root->right == NULL)) {
            struct Node* temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;

            if(temp == NULL){
                temp = root;
                root = NULL;
            } else 
                *root = *temp; 

            free(temp);
        } else{

            struct Node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);

            root->data = temp->data;

            root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->data);
            
        }
    }

    if(root == NULL)
        return root;

    root->height = 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right));

    int balance = getBalance(root);

    if(balance > 1 && getBalance(root->left) >= 0)
        return rightRotate(root);

    if(balance > 1 && getBalance(root->left) < 0) {
        root->left = leftRotate(root->left);
        return rightRotate(root);
    }

    if(balance < -1 && getBalance(root->right) >= 0) {
        root->right = rightRotate(root->right);
        return leftRotate(root);
    }

    if(balance < -1 && getBalance(root->right) < 0)
        return leftRotate(root);

    return root;
}

struct Node* search(struct Node* root, int data) {
    if(root == NULL || root->data == data)
        return root;

    if(root->data < data)
        return search(root->right, data);

    return search(root->left, data);
}

void preorder(struct Node* root) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

void inorder(struct Node* root) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

void postorder(struct Node* root) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        postorder(root->left);
        postorder(root->right);
        printf("%d ", root->data);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Node* root = NULL;
    int choice, data;

    do{
        printf("\n1. Insertion");
        printf("\n2. Deletion");
        printf("\n3. Traversal");
        printf("\n4. Exit");
        printf("\nChoose: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the value to be inserted: ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                root = insert(root, data);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Enter the value to be deleted: ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                if (search(root, data) == NULL) {
                    printf("Data not found.\n");
                } else {
                    root = deleteNode(root, data);
                    printf("Data deleted successfully.\n");
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nPreorder traversal: ");
                preorder(root);
                printf("\nInorder traversal: ");
                inorder(root);
                printf("\nPostorder traversal: ");
                postorder(root);
                printf("\n");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Thank You\n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("Invalid choice\n");
                break;
        }
    } while(choice != 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The results of the AVL Tree transversal print that has been input are correct, but when deleting it and print it again it looks like something is wrong.

**You are mistaken.**

> Here what i input: : 6, 27, 19, 11, 36, 14, 81, 63, 75 And here the output transversal: Preorder traversal: 19 11 6 14 36 27 75 63 81 Inorder traversal: 6 11 14 19 27 36 63 75 81 Postorder traversal: 6 14 11 27 63 81 75 36 19
>
> And i believe it is correct.

The in-order traversal reflects correct BST structure (it traverses the nodes in numerical order).  From the pre- or post-order traversal we can reconstruct the actual tree:

```
      19
    /    \
  11      36
 /  \    /  \
6  14  27   75
           /  \
          63   81
```

This is indeed a valid AVL tree: no node has child subtrees that
differ in height by more than one.

> But after deletion for: 14, 75, 36, 19, 11 Preorder traversal: 27 6 63
> 81 Inorder traversal: 6 27 63 81 Postorder traversal: 6 81 63 27
>
> I think its incorrect because it should be: Preorder traversal: 63 6
> 27 81 Inorder traversal: 27 6 63 81 Postorder traversal: 27 6 81 63

If the tree resulting from your deletions had the in-order traversal you predict, then it would not be a valid BST, much less an AVL tree.  However, the in-order you present also is not consistent with the pre- and post-order you present.

**Is the observed result correct?**  It reflects this final tree:

```
  27
 /  \
6    63
      \
       81
```

This is a valid AVL tree containing the expected elements, so it is plausible for it to be the correct result.

However, there is another valid AVL tree containing the same elements (the one given by your pre- and post-order predictions, with 63 at its root), so let's take a closer look at the actual deletions:

- 14 is a leaf node and its sibling is also a leaf node, so deleting 14 does not require any additional restructuring to speak of.
- The two children of 75 are both leaf nodes.  When 75 is deleted, one of those needs to be promoted to parent of the other to maintain the BST condition, but that does not imbalance the tree.  One valid result would be:

  ```
        19
      /    \
    11      36
   /       /  \
  6      27    63
                \
                 81
  ```
- When 36 is deleted, either the rightmost node in the left subtree (27) or the leftmost node in the right subtree (63) needs to be chosen to replace it.  If we choose 27 then the result will be imbalanced, and we'll need to perform a rotation to rebalance it.  If we choose 63 then the result will be balanced.  As it turns out, the final result is the same either way:

  ```
        19
      /    \
    11      63
   /       /  \
  6      27    81
  ```

  *Note: the choice in the previous step between promoting 63 or 81 is mooted here.  Either alternative leads to the same result tree at the current step.*
- now we delete 19.  Again, we choose as its replacement either the rightmost node of the left subtree (11), or the leftmost node of the right subtree (27).  Either way, the tree remains balanced.  The possible outcomes are:

  ```
        11                   27
      /    \               /    \
     6      63     OR    11      63
           /  \         /          \
         27    81      6            81

        A                    B
  ```
- Finally, we delete 11.

  The result of that on alternative (B) is easy: 6 moves up, the tree is still balanced, done.  Final result:

  ```
       27
     /    \
    6      63
             \
              81
       B
  ```

  Note that **that is the final tree that is actually observed.**

  The result on (A) goes via two alternatives:

  1. We choose the replacement from the right subtree (27).  No rebalancing is required in this case:

     ```
          27
        /    \
       6      63
                \
                 81
          A1
     ```

     Note that **that's also the observed final tree**.  For completeness, however ...
  2. We choose the replacement from the left subtree (6).  In this case, we do need to rebalance, applying a rotation to transform from this:

     ```
            6
              \
               63
              /  \
            27    81

           A2'
     ```

     ... to this final result:

     ```
           63
         /    \
        6      81
         \
          27

           A2
     ```

     This is the alternative AVL tree I mentioned above, and that you predicted.

Ultimately, then, the observed result is plausible for properly-functioning AVL tree routines, though your expectation (as judged by the pre- and post-orders) is plausible as well.  This particular test does not fully exercise the behaviors required for maintaining an AVL tree, but the AVL implementation does seem to pass it, unless, possibly, you must comply with additional constraints beyond simply maintaining the AVL condition with each operation.

HOWEVER, as an implementation strategy, when deleting a node whose child subtrees differ in height, it makes sense to choose the replacement from the taller subtree.  This will tend to reduce the amount of rebalancing that needs to be performed.  AVL routines that use that strategy will produce only the result with root 27 for this test case.